# javafx ComboBoxTableCell

Tags: java, combobox, javafx-8, fxml

I need to add compobox cell to my javafx view. I have fount a lot of solutions how to do it in controller. But I whant do it in fxml file.
So, I have such code:

```
<TableColumn text="Name">
                <cellFactory>
                    <ComboBoxTableCell fx:factory="forTableColumn">
                    </ComboBoxTableCell>
                </cellFactory>
                <cellValueFactory>
                    <PropertyValueFactory property="prop1" />
                </cellValueFactory>
</TableColumn>
```

In ComboBoxTableCell method forTableColumn has params - items. So, how could I fill this items?

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to pass the items to a factory method. You would either need to define a custom class implementing the callback to use as the cell factory, or just do this in the controller.

Comment: It is sad. Thank you

Comment: I am not accepting the comment that there is not way to pass items to the factory method. This seems like such a basic rudimentary function.